# Is there a git hook that runs immediately after detecting a modified file?

Tags: git, githooks, git-status

Let's say after **git pull**-*ing*-or-**git clone**-*ing*, Juan edited a single file called `hello-world.txt`.

Is there a git hook that runs immediately after the modification of the said file?

Comment: Modifying a file does not trigger any git commands or hooks. [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

Comment: could yo explain your task more? Maybe clean/smudge or some other filter is what you are looking for

Comment: I am trying to "auto **git push**" in case there were hot fixes in the production. I don't know if that really makes sense on your end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's possible because there is no hook for file update.

Here's the complete list of hooks available.

```
applypatch-msg
pre-applypatch
post-applypatch
pre-commit
prepare-commit-msg
commit-msg
post-commit
pre-rebase
post-checkout
post-merge
pre-receive
update
post-receive
post-update
pre-auto-gc
post-rewrite
pre-push
```

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Git does not have a hook for that, but there are many other tools you can use to watch for changes to files and then run a command. They do require you to start the tool before you make the modification, though.

Some tools are listed in the answers to [How to execute a command whenever a file changes?](https://superuser.com/q/181517/124606). Here are two examples:

Running `make` automatically with [`entr`](http://entrproject.org/):

```
echo hello-world.txt | entr make
```

Running `make` automatically with [`watchexec`](https://github.com/mattgreen/watchexec):

```
watchexec --exts txt make
```

If you don’t want to have to start the watching tool yourself, you could try starting it in a Git hook such as `post-receive`.